# Trimmed string change it's length only by half

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, trim, objective-c++, string-length

Could anyone give some advise please.
In my iOS app I am parsing XML (with a help of third-party-library) and have a problem with extra whitespaces/newLines at the beginning/end of the strings. Initial string, that return this third-party-library, it's a C++ `std::wstring` that I convert to `NSString` (the encoding should be right as the content of new `NSString` is equal to proper part of my XML-file). After the trim length of "empty" elements (that contain only whitespaces and new lines) doesn't become zero but change it's value by half. 
The code is below....

```
std::wstring val;
NSString *initial = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:val.data() length:sizeof (wchar_t)*val.size() encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSString *trimmed = [initial stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

If try to output like `NSLog(@"bybyby'%@'bebebe", trimmed);` 'bebebe have never displayed. Looks like that there are left some new lines, whitespaces that can't be detected.

Comment: Are you sure UTF16 is correct? Did you try with UTF8? Logging the string before trimming shows no issues?

Comment: @Wain yes, I tried UTF8 - the problem with "empty" elements is still there, plus - elements that contain some text encoded incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wchar_t` is a 32-bit integer (on iOS and OS X), therefore you must use `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding` for the conversion to `NSString`.

Example:

```
std::wstring val (L"   Hello World   ");
NSString *initial = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:val.data() length:sizeof (wchar_t)*val.size() encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSString *trimmed = [initial stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"'%@'", trimmed);
// Output: 'Hello World'
```

What probably happened in your case (with `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding`)
is that every second character in the `initial` string is a NUL character,
which acts as a terminator when printed.

Comment: encoding 'NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding' helps, but only for elements like "\n" even one more additional whitespace in it and result of 'NSString *initial = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:val.data() length:sizeof (wchar_t)*val.size() encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];' is 'nil' (as for all other elements that contain some text)

Comment: @PolinaKhorolets: Strange, I tested the above code. - Can you try the following (with a "problematic" string): `NSLog(@"data=%@", [NSData dataWithBytes:val.data() length:sizeof(wchar_t)*val.size()]);` and show the result?

Comment: data=<0a002000 20002000 20000000 00000000 00000000> it's for 'wstring' with lenght=10 that looks like "\n   " after converting to 'NSString'

Comment: @PolinaKhorolets: That looks as if `val` does not really contain `wchar_t` elements, but 16-bit characters, such as `unichar`.

Comment: O, yeh) thanks a lot!! placing unichar instead of wchar_t when transforming std::wstring into NSString solve the problem)